# How can I bring back icons on the notification to the sytem tray area?

Tags: skype, notification

I just installed Skype. Now the first thing I noticed is that when I minimized Skype it doesn't show an icon on the system tray. Also, not only Skype, I don't see any minimize programs in Skype. I want to have a notification everytime I received a message when Skype is minimized. Instead, it goes to the launcher, which I find annoying since I autohide it. How can I bring back icons on the notification @ system tray area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer at [this similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/220760/no-icon-with-skype-4-1-in-ubuntu-12-04) of running `sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386` and then starting skype worked for me just a few mins ago. And I'm on x64 - I didn't need to change to a 64-bit specific version.

Comment: What exactly that command means?

Comment: It installs a small package that adjusts some settings that allow Skype and the tray to work together. You run it from terminal, which you open with Ctrl+Alt+T. You'll need to enter your password.
Alternatively, you can search for "Indicator support for Qt" and install it from Ubuntu Software Center - different path to installing the same thing.

Comment: Ok thanks, it works now. Still I'm confused what does that `sni-qt` did to make it work.

Comment: Qt is the software framework that Skype (and many other apps) are built with. The sni-qt package allows Qt-based indicators to interoperate with the Ubuntu Panel.